# Pandas drop duplicates; values in reverse order

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, duplicates

I'm trying to find a way to utilize pandas `drop_duplicates()` to recognize that rows are duplicates when the values are in reverse order.

An example is if I am trying to find transactions where customers purchases both apples and bananas, but the data collection order may have reversed the items. In other words, when combined as a full order the transaction is seen as a duplicate because it is made up up of the same items.

I want the following to be recognized as duplicates:

```
Item1   Item2
Apple   Banana
Banana  Apple
```

Answer (score 5):

First sort by rows with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `sorted` and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.apply(sorted, axis=1).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   Item1   Item2
0  Apple  Banana
```

---

```
#if need specify columns
cols = ['Item1','Item2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
print (df)
   Item1   Item2
0  Apple  Banana
```

Another solution with [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
       .drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   Item1   Item2
0  Apple  Banana
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was driving me crazy because I figured it was simple. I like the third option the best. Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, it is fastest, because `numpy`. Glad can help you!

Comment: the last option is very nice!

Comment: @MaxU  -Thank you.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me only after setting result_type='expand' on the apply function