# Dropping duplicate rows, while ignoring column ordering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset where the ordering of the columns is meaningless, but the combination of columns is meaningful. In other words, in the following dataframe example:

```
| A | B | C | D |
|---------------|
| h | i | j | k |
| k | j | h | k |
```

Where `[A,B,C,D]` are column headers, and `[h,i,j,k]` are cell values- `row 1` and `row 2` can be considered identical.

The problem I am trying to solve is to delete this second row, in principle. I am familiar with the usage of: `df.delete_duplicates()`, however this does not see these two rows as equivalent.
A solution I thought might work would be to sort each row alphabetically, but I cant figure a way to do this.

Help much appreciated,

Luke

Comment: The first row has `i` value, the second doesn't. How are they identical? Also you should add the `pandas` tag and remove the `jupyter-notebook` one =).

Comment: If in second row is typo and need `i` instead `k`, then use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43528612/2901002)

Answer (score 0):

Hope that order of values doesn't matter :)

```
import pandas as pd
a = list('hkjk')
b = list('kjhk')
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b], columns=list('ABCD'))
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df = df.to_dict(orient='index')
new_records = {k1: list(sorted([v2 for k2, v2 in v1.items()])) for k1, v1 in df.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame([v for _, v in new_records.items()], columns = cols)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```