# Pandas drop duplicates (also reverse order) (Python 3.7)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

My data looks the following:

```
Key1 Key2 Value1 Info1 Info2 Info3 ...
1      2    5.5   255   232   2
2      1    4.9   200   200   1
3      1    2.2   100   100   5
```

I want to drop duplicates based on Key1 and Key2. I also see keys in reverse order as duplicates (1,2)=(2,1). 
Desired result:

```
Key1 Key2 Value1 Info1 Info2 Info3 ...
1      2    5.5   255   232   2
3      1    2.2   100   100   5
```

I tried with the following approach:
[Pandas drop duplicates; values in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528573/pandas-drop-duplicates-values-in-reverse-order)

```
cols = ['Key1','Key2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
```

This error comes:
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

I also tried to avoid having NaN in Key1/Key2 so at first I do

```
df=df.fillna(0)
```

but it also doesn't work.